# How can I elegantly dismiss view if at the moment of dismissing I don't know that view is fully created?

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uistoryboard

How can I elegantly dismiss view if at the moment of dismissing I don't know if that view is fully created ?

Here is my dilemma. The view is showing some data that is requested from the server. Therefore I asynchronously send server request from `viewDidLoad` and wait in two observers if request failed or not.

For "dismissing" view I use exit segue (storyboard).

So there are two scenarios:

- Server-side error occurred after `viewDidAppear` was called. Then I can call `performSegue` or `self.navigationController.pop...` and everything is nice.
- Server-side error occurred before `viewDidAppear` was called. How can I navigate user to previous view in this case ?

For now I just put server request to `viewDidAppear` but it's very uncool because user looks at empty view for significant amount of time :(

How would you deal with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out there [is `int` flag](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/UIKit/UIViewController2.h#L67) in `UIViewController` that is called `_appearState`. When it's 2 that means view has appeared.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED
Make a flag, i.e.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL requestFailedOrViewDidAppear;
```

set it to NO at start of viewDidLoad or in init method. Then in your server-side error handler do something like this:

```
if (requestFailedOrViewDidAppear) {
    //return to previous view
}
else {
    requestFailedOrViewDidAppear = YES;
}
```

Put the same code into viewDidAppear, too.

That is more elegant in terms of implementation. However if you want it to be elegant in terms of UI/UX, replace "//return to previous view" with code that creates and shows a UIAlertView explaining the error. Then, when user dismisses that alert view, you can return to the previous view.

Comment: And what if server was slow and error event arrived **after** `viewDidAppear` was called ? :)

Comment: Then either make another flag to check if viewDidAppear was called, or use just one flag and then set it in viewDidAppear to YES. In your error handler check if it is set to YES and, if it is, return to previous view. But better change the name "requestFailed" to something else in that case.

Comment: Yeah.. But two flags is already too much boiledplate code. It should be something more nice..

Comment: One flag is enough. But you should name it different than requestFailed. Like requestFailedOrViewDidAppear, but probably there is a better name for it. I'll update the answer to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your user will expect some info to be shown on the view that's being presented, If the request fails before `viewDidAppear`, I would wait until view appears, show the error, and dismiss the view. Else if request fails after `viewDidAppear`, I would just show the error and dismiss the view on the request observing method. That would be my way of dealing with this problem.

Comment: How can I wait for view to appear ?

Comment: Use some boolean flag, change flag's value on `viewDidAppear`, and observe it's value, and if request already failed, show error and dismiss the view.